# Integrate nodejs into existing site

Tags: node.js

I am kind of new to nodejs. I learnt programming by myself so my programming routines are kind of messy. But here's something that's been bothering me for a while. I already have a site running on jquery, php and mysql. It has multiple features which it uses ajax for. These features (modules) include profile modules (facebook type wall), messaging modules, etc.

Now I want to make server push updates to the client, like if a new message arrives or if someone posts on the wall. I don't want to create everything on nodejs again. I just need to tell client (dom) that new updates have arrived so ajax jquery functions that fetch data can now be triggered.

So my question is, is this possible? If so how?

EDIT: I found similar discussion here: [Node + now.js + Model-View-Control-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973071/node-now-js-model-view-control-pattern)